# Help with momentum question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, momentum

What is the magnitude of momentum of a particle whose mass is $60\,\mathrm{MeV}/c^2$ and whose total energy is $100\,\mathrm{MeV}$?  Again, give your answer in $\mathrm{MeV}/c$.

Imagine that the photon from the first question is moving in the $xy$-plane, at an angle of $60$ degrees to the $x$-axis.  What is the $x$-component of its momentum, in $\mathrm{MeV}/c$?

Attempt:

I understand the first part and got $80\,\mathrm{MeV}/c$ for the momentum, but I do not know how to do the second part. I thought you could just go $80\cos(60) = p_x$

Comment: Momentum of a photon is given by p=h/(lambda).  Also, photons don't have rest mass, so be careful in calculating momentum and energy based on the same equations that you would use for particles that do have rest mass.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).